# Spring MVC duplicate requests ignoring checks in the service layer

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using the spring-boot mvc in my project and there is a strange issue that I am facing.

I have this method in my service layer

```
@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;

public void registerUser(User user) {

    User existingUser = userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername());

    if (existingUser != null) {
        throw new UserException("Sorry! This username is already taken");
    }
    // other validations
    userRepository.save(user);
}
```

Surprisingly , there are entries into the database that have the same username. This happens when the the front-end POSTs multiple requests for the same form content.

I have two questions:

1 .Is there an option for me to stop this at the back-end (Java)in addtion to asking the front-end to disable the submit button after click?

2. Will it be a security risk if it is handled only on the front-end?

Comment: You should have define unique constraint for the username also you could disable the submit button once it is clicked.

Comment: Agreed. But is there a way I can handle concurrent requests while using the spring-mvc?

Comment: making your method syncronnous would do that but it will slow your application little bit.but it is one way of approaching the problem may give it a try